# How to get list of font names from Java

Tags: java, fonts, awt

In Java we can create a Font object as such:

```
new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);
```

My question is how do we get the entire list of font names from Java, for example "Helvetica" which we can use it as one the argument for the Font constructor?

I tried the following, but I can't find "Helvetica" in all of the lists.

```
    GraphicsEnvironment ge;  
    ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();  

    String[] names = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    Font[] allFonts = ge.getAllFonts();

    for(int x=0; x<names.length; x++)
        System.out.println(names[x]);

    for(int x=0; x<allFonts.length; x++){           
        System.out.println(allFonts[x].getName());
        System.out.println(allFonts[x].getFontName());
        System.out.println(allFonts[x].getFamily());
        System.out.println(allFonts[x].getPSName());
    }
```

---

**Edit:** More importantly, I also want to know what  is the first attribute call in Font constructor`new Font("What attribute is this?", Font.PLAIN, 12)`

**Q: Is it a fontName, family, fontFace, name or what?**

Comment: Can you provide output? In my case I see more than 10 strings contains `Helivetica` word.

Comment: @maxd I hope I could, as that will be useful to you all, but my output s too long. over 3000 lines of fonts.

Comment: Just past it to gist.github.com or pastebin.com

Comment: Could you please specify your OS too?

Comment: @maxd Window 7 Home Premium SP 1

Comment: [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) is a answer on your question about first String argument of Font class.

Comment: @maxd thanks for your effort, I already went to that page several times today already. But still unsure which `name` is it referring to. Can I assume the `name` mentioned in the API is same as what I can receive from `allFonts[x].getName()` ?

Answer (score 8):

On your system, that font may well be mapped to something else

```
Font helvetica = new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);
System.out.println(helvetica.getFontName(Locale.US));
```

and I get

```
SansSerif.plain
```

To output the names of all local fonts, you could use something like

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment
        .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();

Font[] allFonts = ge.getAllFonts();

for (Font font : allFonts) {
    System.out.println(font.getFontName(Locale.US));
}
```

Comment: @ElliotFrisch Thanks for your help, but I still don't see it in my list of fonts. What is the "helvetica" I am looking for. Is it call fontName, family, fontFace or font or name? Knowing that, I will be able to know which method to use to grab the list of allowable string to fill the Font constructor. Thanks!

Comment: It's the font name, and it starts with a capital letter and it may not be available on your system (it isn't on mine).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your relpy. So I guess I can simply use `allFonts[x].getFontName()` ? I was confused because the API only mentioned `name` instead of `fontName`.

Comment: Fonts (and typography) are a somewhat complex topic, and the name [Helvetica](http://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica) refers to a typeface. You can call [`Font.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getName%28%29) which *Returns the logical name of this `Font`* and/or [`Font.getFontName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#getFontName%28%29) which says (as an example) that *Helvetica Bold could be returned as a font face name*.

Answer (score 4):

```
new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 12);
```

In this case, it is better to use something like:

```
new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 12);
```

That will produce the undecorated `Font` used by default on that OS.

On Windows it would be Arial.  On OS X it would be Helvetica.  On *nix machines it might be either, or a 3rd undecorated `Font`.

---

In answer to your specific question, I've always found the 'font family' string to be useful for creating an instance of the font.

Answer (score 4):

this programme will show you list of all font in you system :

```
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

public class ListJavaFonts
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String fonts[] = 
      GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

    for ( int i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++ )
    {
      System.out.println(fonts[i]);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but there are some unanswered questions.

> More importantly, I also want to know what is the first attribute call in Font constructor new Font("What attribute is this?", Font.PLAIN, 12)  Q: Is it a fontName, family, fontFace, name or what?

If you decompile the Java class with an IDE (I'm using IntelliJ), you will see:

```
public Font(String name, int style, int size) {
    this.name = (name != null) ? name : "Default";
    this.style = (style & ~0x03) == 0 ? style : 0;
    this.size = size;
    this.pointSize = size;
}
public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
public String getFontName() {
  return getFontName(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

This tells you that the name you use when calling the constructor can be retrieved with getName, but a call to getFontName will return your default text.  That is why you can set the name to Helvetica, then call getFontName and it return something other than Helvetica.